# Why is SQL Server Database User Writing to the Wrong Schema?

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In my database, I have 2 schemas: **[dbo]** and **[rch]** (`[rch]` was selected as the name for our "archived" data so that those tables would not appear before the `[dbo]` tables).

I created a user for this table called **rchuser** in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

[image: general]

- Notice above that the user is added with `rch` listed as the Default Schema.

[image: owned]

- Notice above that this new user owns both `db_owner` and `rch`.

[image: membership]

Let's say I have this SQL insert:

```
public static int AddRecord(object value, string sqlConnection)
{
    int result = 0;
    using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sqlCmd =
            "INSERT INTO Table1 ([Value], [Stamp]) " +
            "VALUES (@Value, GETDATE()); ";
        using (var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlCmd, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value);
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I passed that method a connection string using my `rchuser` credentials.

```
 var conn = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DatabaseN;User Id=rchuser;Password=password;"
```

There is no error, result is 1, but the new record is NOT in the corresponding table for my `[rch]` schema.

It is like the database is completely ignoring the fact that this user defaults to the `[rch]` schema.

I even tried logging into the SSMS database with `rchuser` to execute the command by hand. Again, no errors. The data went into `[dbo]`.

### How do I direct all database input to go to another schema?

Comment: Oh: Using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Could you verify Table1 exists in this other schema?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes I created the table in the other schema. It isn't called **Table1** and the catalog isn't **DatabaseN**. My employer is a bit paranoid out his info getting online.

Comment: What if you take back the dbo ownership (second screen)?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - The `rchuser` then can't open the database. It may still be able to call in code. I didn't check that part. Specifying `[rch]` as the default should have done it, from my understanding.

Comment: That's a bit odd. The user owns a schema with tables and can't open the database? Sounds like something weird you could try to track down.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - The [dbo] schema is in the same table. **I guess** if [rchuser] only has access to [rch] schema in that table, SSMS won't let that user view the data.

Comment: Could you please check probably login "rchuser" has server role sysadmin.? If it's so then all the queries will use schema "dbo" by default

Comment: Table? Database, I guess. Anyway, what ssms has to do with the query you send from a c# code? My advice was to take back the ownership of the dbo schema and run the code, not ssms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple schemas in a database, then my recommendation is to always explicitly specify which one you want. Aaron Bertrand has [a good article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) on why you should do it, even if you only have one schema.

So modify your sql statement to be

`INSERT INTO [rch].Table1...`

and you will be all good.

I do note that this doesn't answer your title, but it does answer your question.

As to why your query isn't defaulting to the [rch] schema, I don't know. I replicated your setup in SQL Server 2008 R2, and when I run your original query then the inserts do go into the rch table as expected.

EDIT:

I did some Googling, and I suspect that your problem is caused by granting the `sysadmin` server role to the `rchuser` login. I modified mine to be an sa

[image: Login Properties screenshot]

, and now the inserts go into the [dbo] schema by default, even though rchuser has a default schema of [rch].

So, if you remove the `sysadmin` server role, it should start working as expected.

Comment: An upvote for replicating it. Perhaps something is askew in my SSMS. The other answer also specified to explicitly call the schema, too.

Comment: @jp2code Perhaps delete the user and re-create them. That might be enough to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this. I had to reassign the owner of the other schema to **[dbo]** before I could delete and recreate the new user. Now to see if it works....

Comment: Oh man! I dug down deep into that code. The data adapter, under the hood, is hard coded to put everything out there as "UPDATE dbo.Table..." or "INSERT INTO dbo.Table...". I now have the methods that call that configured to pass it a parameter indicating if this is an archive or live data. Thanks Dean! You forced me to keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

Have You tried to specifiy schema for table in Your query?

```
var sqlCmd =
            "INSERT INTO rch.Table1 ([Value], [Stamp]) " +
            "VALUES (@Value, GETDATE()); ";
```

Comment: That would likely work (+1). This is a large project using custom data adapters to manipulate the data, though. Most data will be going to `[dbo]`. 245 tables for this particular customer, so all of the SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT commands would need to be hunted down in the auto generated code and modified to have that field as a parameter.

Comment: If you use a layer like an orm that doesn't support explicit schemas in queries, setting up a default schema is the only option.